# Calculating variance of a dependent variable with multiple fixed effects

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, variance, lme4-nlme

I am kind of a stats noob but I figure someone here may have some insight. I am running a linear mixed effects model in R, reminiscent of what's below:

```r
model <- lmer(rating ~  group * cond1 * cond2 + (1|subject) + 
                        (1|image), data=data1)
```

I also want to compare the variances of ratings between my two groups. As of yet, I have been using `var.test` to compare variances across my two other conditions. That said, I am also interested in, for lack of a better word, the interaction between these fixed effects (group and conditions) on variances of ratings. It doesn't seem this is possible with `var.test` and I'm frankly unsure if it's possible at all. Would someone be able to offer some clarity or an R function that could compute what I'm interested in?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing so?

Comment: We are comparing a clinical population's performance in a cognitive task to a control population. The literature supports that this clinical population tends to show distinct patterns of variance in cognitive tasks. Therefore, comparing variances between groups is informative.

Comment: How is variance measured in the literature? Descriptively? With only two groups (clinical/non-clinical), the multilevel model will give you a variance, but it's not designed with that purpose in mind. Also, the multilevel model is splitting variance based on the random effects (subject and image), not the fixed effects. Fixed effect predictors can increase or decrease the estimated random effect variances.

Comment: I agree with Erik's commentary on this. I may provide a more detailed answer about why I don't like the $F$ test here, but I had another question. I just noticed that I see `cond1` and `cond2` in your regression. What are these supposed to signify? If these are two conditions that belong to an overall factor, they shouldn't be separate. For example, if condition can be meaningfully separated into "Control" and "Treatment", these are not separate predictors...they are the same factor and should be entered only as one predictor with dummy coding.

Comment: I agree with @ShawnHemelstrand that visualizing the variability in your data is a great place to start. What kind of scale is `rating`, what kind of values do the ratings take?

Answer (score 2):

I'll just go ahead and answer with the assumption that your two `cond` variables are separate factors. If they are not, they should really be entered as one predictor with some dummy coding. In any case, because you are working with a three-way interaction, the effect here is likely to be very weak and thus will be difficult to test unless you have a study that is well-powered. Even for just a simple two-way interaction, you need approximately four times the sample of one with only main effects due to the increased standard error (Gelman et al., 2022, p.301-302), so this is magnified with more complex interactions.

I don't know if it is necessarily useful to do any formal NHST tests of variance. The problem with a formal test like the $F$ test is that it tests if there is no difference between the variances and rejecting such a test simply makes the following claim: "The probability of the observed variance is too low to say that the variances from both groups are the same." Great. We pretty much *necessarily* expect there to be a difference in the variance between groups, and a variance test isn't going to spell out what the magnitude of that difference is, so I don't find that to be all that useful (for more info on what the $p$ value of such a test really means, see Wasserstein & Lazar, 2016). Your major objective here is to find out *just how much* they differ in variance, which a null test doesn't do.

The shorter and simpler answer is that you can directly observe this by simply exploring it in your data with R either by describing or visualizing your data by its structure. Here is a simple example using a two-factor grouping. We can easily describe the data by using the `tidyverse` and grouping the data before summarizing the mean, variance, and SD. Here I use the `carrots` data from the `lmerTest` package and recode the data so it is slightly more interpretable.

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(tidyverse)
library(lmerTest)

#### Turn Data into Tibble ####
tib <- carrots %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Homesize = ifelse(Homesize == 3, "3 or More People", "1-2 People"),
         Frequency = factor(case_when(
           Frequency == 1 ~  "Once a week or more",
           Frequency == 2 ~  "Once every two weeks",
           Frequency == 3 ~  "Once every three weeks",
           Frequency == 4 ~  "At least once a month",
           Frequency == 5 ~  "Less than once a month"
         )))
tib

#### Summarize By-Group Comparisons ####
tib %>% 
  group_by(Homesize,
           Frequency) %>% 
  summarise(Mean.Pref = mean(Preference, na.rm=T),
            Var.Pref = var(Preference, na.rm = T),
            SD.Pref = sd(Preference, na.rm=T))
```

We now have our descriptive data, where the variance doesn't change much in most groups but can vary to a degree in some:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 5
# Groups:   Homesize [2]
  Homesize         Frequency      Mean.Pref Var.Pref SD.Pref
  <chr>            <fct>              <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1-2 People       At least once…      4.25    0.386   0.622
2 1-2 People       Once a week o…      4.98    1.57    1.25 
3 1-2 People       Once every th…      4.58    1.23    1.11 
4 1-2 People       Once every tw…      4.90    1.14    1.07 
5 3 or More People At least once…      4.42    1.36    1.16 
6 3 or More People Less than onc…      4.89    2.22    1.49 
7 3 or More People Once a week o…      4.63    1.27    1.13 
8 3 or More People Once every th…      4.69    1.08    1.04 
9 3 or More People Once every tw…      4.76    0.887   0.942
```

Visualizing it makes it more clear. One can use a boxplot for this, but a violin plot can also provide more specific information about where data is clustered, giving more information about how each grouping varies. I also overlay some points to make it more visible where the data is.

```
#### Plot Variations ####
tib %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Gender,
             y=Preference))+
  geom_violin()+
  geom_point(position = "jitter")+
  facet_wrap(~ Frequency,
             nrow=1)+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

The first group doesn't have any males, but we can see that the variance shifts to a degree depending on the group, and this information may guide your inference around your `lmer` model to an extent.

##### References

- Gelman, A., Hill, J., & Vehtari, A. (2022). Regression and other stories. Cambridge University Press.
- Wasserstein, R. L., & Lazar, N. A. (2016). The ASA statement on p-values: Context, process, and purpose. The American Statistician, 70(2), 129–133. https://doi.org/10.1080/00031305.2016.1154108